# can anyone help me with the sorting using compare to in array list?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compareto

Hi guys I am making an inventory program and I am having trouble with the stockItem sorting method.which i need to use compareto to solve it.
This is my code so far. Please scroll to the bottom to see what I'm talking about.

```
public class Inventory {
    private ArrayList<StockItem> stock;

    public Inventory() {
        stock = new ArrayList<StockItem>();
    }

    public void addStockItem(StockItem item) {
        stock.add(item);
    }

    public int size() {
        return stock.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for(StockItem item: stock)
            result+=item.toString()+"\n";
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isValidIndex(int index) {
        return index >=0 && index < stock.size();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return null if index is not valid, otherwise
     * return item at that index
     */
    public StockItem getItem(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.stock.size())// check if this index  exists
            return null; // removes the item the from stock and returns it
        else
            return this.stock.get(index);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return null if index is invalid, otherwise remove item at the given
     *         index and return the removed item.
     */
    public StockItem remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.stock.size()) // check if this index  exists
            return null; // removes the item the from stock and returns it
        else
            return this.stock.remove(index);
    }

    /**
     * sort, using {@link StockItem#compareTo(StockItem)}
     * cannot use built-in sort method from java
     */
    public void sort() {

}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What do you want to compare and by which criteria ? can you show us what you've tried and what was the outcome (vs. expected outcome) ?

Comment: You need to share your StackItem class with the sorting criteria you want. (e.g. do you want them to be sorted by stackitem's quantity ?)

Answer (score 0):

**I guess that you want to order your items by their sizes**. You may use any existing algorithm for sorting such as [selection sort](https://sortingalgorithms.quora.com/Selection-Sort), [insertion sort](https://sortingalgorithms.quora.com/Insertion-Sort) or [bubble sort](https://sortingalgorithms.quora.com/Bubble-Sort). Furthermore, it is possible to use the **Java built-in method from Collections module** which is much faster and easier to implement. You may use **Collections.sort() method** given that your class is implementing *Comparable interface* and its abstract method *compareTo()*. You can implement comapreTo() method manually or just use Integer class to do so. I used the second approach. I am building a StockItem class with the necessary methods and fields you need to sort. Your code for Inventory should look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Inventory {

    private ArrayList<StockItem> stock;

    public Inventory() {
        stock = new ArrayList<StockItem>();
    }

    public void addStockItem(StockItem item) {
        stock.add(item);
    }

    public int size() {
        return stock.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for(StockItem item: stock)
            result+=item.toString()+"\n";
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isValidIndex(int index) {
        return index >=0 && index < stock.size();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return null if index is not valid, otherwise
     * return item at that index
     */
    public StockItem getItem(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.stock.size())// check if this index  exists
            return null; // removes the item the from stock and returns it
        else
            return this.stock.get(index);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return null if index is invalid, otherwise remove item at the given
     *         index and return the removed item.
     */
    public StockItem remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.stock.size()) // check if this index  exists
            return null; // removes the item the from stock and returns it
        else
            return this.stock.remove(index);
    }

    /**
     * sort, using {@link StockItem#compareTo(StockItem)}
     * cannot use built-in sort method from java
     */
    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(stock);
    }
}
```

and your code for StockItem class should be similar to the following:

```
    public class StockItem implements Comparable<StockItem>{
    private int size;
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
    public Integer getSizeNonPrimativeInt() {
        return new Integer(this.getSize());
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(StockItem item) {
        return this.getSizeNonPrimativeInt().compareTo(item.getSizeNonPrimativeInt());
    }
}
```

Hope this help ;)

Comment: but we can not use built-in sort method from java, and we are new to java ,therefore im confused about what u just did ;（

Comment: I used the built-in method in your sort() function. Where did you get confused? Can you explain your confusion?

Answer (score 0):

You have not pasted your code for **StockItem** class. So I assume a sample class below and you can change your code accordingly. Lets assume your **StockItem** class like below:

```
class StockItem{

  private String itemName;
  private double itemPrice;

  public String getItemName() {
      return itemName;
  }

  public void setItemName(String itemName) {
      this.itemName = itemName;
  }

  public double getItemPrice() {
      return itemPrice;
  }

  public void setItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
      this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
  }

}
```

You mentioned you cannot use in-built sort() method from Collections, but I guess you might be pointed out you cannot use sort() method just because it sorts **not the way you wanted**? You need to define a comparator object with your custom sorting criteria and pass it to your in-built sort() method.

```
public class Inventory {

private ArrayList<StockItem> stock;

//-- your other code segments

  static class ListComparator implements Comparator<StockItem>{
      @Override
      public int compare(StockItem o1, StockItem o2) {
          if(o1.getItemName().compareTo(o2.getItemName())>0){
              return 1;
          }
          else if(o1.getItemName().compareTo(o2.getItemName())<0){
              return -1;
          }
          else
              return 0;
      } 
  } 

  public void sort() {
      Collections.sort(stock, new ListComparator());
  }
}
```